# Convert int64 to datetime with format %H:%M'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df_h00 = df.copy()
tt = df_h00.set_index('username').post_time_data.str.extractall(r'totalCount\":([^,}]*)')
tt['index']=tt.index
tt[['user','hour']]=pd.DataFrame(tt['index'].values.tolist(),
                        index=tt.index)
tt = tt.drop(['index'], axis=1)
tt.columns = ['totalCount', 'user', 'hours']
tt.head()

                totalCount  user   hours
username  match         
lowi      0        15       lowi    0
          1        11       lowi    1
          2        2        lowi    2
          3        0        lowi    3
          4        0        lowi    4
```

I want to convert the column tt['hours'] which is `non-null int64` to date time with format "%H:%M".
I've tried the following code:

```
tthour = tt['hours']
tthour = pd.to_datetime(tthour, format='%H', errors='coerce')
tthour = tthour.to_frame()
tthour.head()

                        hours
username  match 
lowi       0    1900-01-01 00:00:00
           1    1900-01-01 01:00:00
           2    1900-01-01 02:00:00
           3    1900-01-01 03:00:00
           4    1900-01-01 04:00:00
```

However, I only want "%H:%M". So the expected output would be like this:

```
                  hours
username  match 
lowi       0      00:00
           1      01:00
           2      02:00
           3      03:00
           4      04:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Datetimes in your expected format not exist in python.

Close what you need are [timedeltas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html) by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) or strings:

```
tt = pd.DataFrame({'hours':np.arange(5)})
tt['td'] = pd.to_timedelta(tt['hours'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + ':00:00',  errors='coerce')
tt['str'] = tt['hours'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + ':00'
print (tt)
   hours       td    str
0      0 00:00:00  00:00
1      1 01:00:00  01:00
2      2 02:00:00  02:00
3      3 03:00:00  03:00
4      4 04:00:00  04:00
```

Comment: doesn't work because it also counts days and in some cases it's counting 1 day instead of 0 and when I group by `tt['td']` I get rows from `0 days 00:00:00` to `0 days 23:00:00`, but then the others rows of day one start (from `1 days 00:00:00` to `1 days 23:00:00`.

Comment: @pesc9 - So use `tt['str'] = tt['hours'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + ':00'`